# Which practice is better performance for comparing two objects

Tags: java, performance

I have an Object as follows

```
class Person {
    String name;
}
```

So if I have to compare in-equality for names of two person objects, which of the following approach is better and why?

Approach 1 :

```
   if (aPerson.getName().equals(bPerson.getName()) == false){
        System.out.println("They are not same person");
   }
```

Approach 2 :

```
    if(!aPerson.getName().equals(bPerson.getName()){
      System.out.println("They are not same person");  
    }
```

I am looking for answers only on performance perspective.

Comment: The performance of every other operation in your code is likely to be far higher. e.g. removing one character from your output is likely to make much more difference. Although in this case, there is no difference.

Comment: This is not exactly same code in my program . I am only interested in learning , if there is any performance different between "!" operation and "==false" operation . This check is invoked close to million times  , so even a small milli secs improvement it can make , matters.

Comment: A millisecond would make a difference but in your case you are talking about nanoseconds or 0.000001 milli-seconds. Actually the code is exactly the same once compiled so it is zero.  Writing to System.out is millions of times more expensive for this sort of operations. even comparing two Strings which have one more character in them is more than 10x more expensive.

Comment: @Jijoy there is _zero_ difference.  _Stop bothering with things like this._

Answer (score 1):

There is no performance difference between the boolean conditions you have shown.

If you really are concerned about that, you are optimizing the wrong code.

If you care about file size, then use shorter variable &  method names

Comment: Technically speaking, a totally brain-dead JVM could have a performance difference, so if there was a difference it would be a signal to ditch the JVM, not optimise your code!